# Enable Labels (via Retention policy) in List: How?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, provisioning

In my SharePoint App, I want to provisioning a document library and set the following list setting:

- Information management policy settings > Set source of retention to "Library and folders"
  [image]
- Information management policy settings > Retention policy > Enable Labels, set label to {Version}
  [image]

How this be done via the CSOM API ? I use SharePoint Online

Answer (score -1):

API to add Policy (label) is only available in Server Side Code, see my workarounds: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154433/csom-issue-workaround-needed-for-systemupdate-disablefiringevents-to-be-able

Comment: The link is broken